# Personal Google search bar blocking jQuery underneath

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, google-search

I recently added a Google search bar to my website. How I found that it is blocking the navigation underneath even when the search is not active. If I bring the navigation z-index up it is then displayed over the search results.  How do I make it so the buttons are "clickable" when the search bar is not rolled down. View page here http://etterengineering.com/SampleIndex.html

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<div id="cse-search-form" style= "z-index:999999; top:0px;"></div>
<div id="cse-search-form" style="width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('search', '1', {language : 'en', style : google.loader.themes.SHINY});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl('012677673255316824096:sean13fvlei');
    customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
    var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
    options.setSearchFormRoot('cse-search-form');
    customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
  }, true);
</script>
<div id="cse" style="width:43%; z-index:999997; top:40px; height:650px;"></div>
```

**And my CSS:**

```
#cse-search-form {
    position:absolute; 
    z-index:999999; 
    width:270px; 
    left:680px;}
#cse{position:absolute; z-index:999997; left: 530px; 
overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden; pointer-events:none;
    }
 #dropdown {      
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 1em;
  }
 #dropdown li {
  float: left;    
  list-style: none;
  }
 #dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  width:12em;     
  padding: 3px 0px;   
  background-color: transparent;      
  white-space:pre;    
  font-size:.8em;
  letter-spacing: -.4px;        
  text-align:center; 
  z-index: 24000;     
  font-family: Verdana;   
  color: #424242;
  position: relative; top:105px; left: 0px;   
  text-decoration: none; 
  }
  #dropdown li a:hover {color:#000000;}
  /* Sub Drop Down Organization */
  #dropdown li ul {
  display: none; 
  width: 18em;    
      letter-spacing:  1em;
  text-align:center;
  }
  /* Sub Drop down Hover */
  #dropdown li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
 #dropdown li:hover li a {
  word-spacing: .025em;       
  letter-spacing: -.05em;     
  font-size:.8em; 
  font-family: Verdana;   
  background: #6e6e6e; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF), to(#ADADAD));
      background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FFFFFF,  #ADADAD);
  }
  #dropdown li li a:hover {color:#ff0000;}
```

Comment: So i have figured out that the pointer-events:none; enables my users to click through to the layer underneath, but then in turn disables the search drop down from being clickable. How can I enable the search drop down when it is down but still use the pointer-events code to enable clicking on the layer beneath when it is invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not the Google search bar, you have a div with an id of "cse" that is preventing clicking of links.

Picture of issue:
[image: click]

CSS:

```
#cse {display:none;}
```

Assign an Id to the search box such as `googleSearch`.

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#googleSearch").focus(function() {
        $("#cse").show();
    });
    $("#googleSearch").blur(function() {
        $("#cse").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: The div is the actual search results which roll down. So unfortunately I can not take that out. Is there another way around this?

Comment: @Stephanie, Hide the div when there is no search results.

Comment: Is this possible without accessing the Google contained javascript?

Comment: @Stephanie, Yes, here is what I would do. Use css to hide that div initially and then when the Google search box has focus then show that div and when the search bar loses focus then hide the div. If you need help with the the jQuery I will take the time to write it for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This does enable me to access the links underneath however it prevents the search results from rolling down. Any other recommendations?

Comment: @Stephanie, Yes, try messing with the `pointer-events` setting initially, and then when the search box is focused set `pointer-events` to none. Then on blur set it back to whatever setting lets you click through. (There are about 10 different settings for pointer-events, so try whichever one lets you click through)